# Restricting Buttons with textAreas

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

My website is meant to be navigated through pressing buttons on the keyboard: <kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>\</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, etc... My issue is that I have textAreas, and when I press these buttons, if the textArea is selected, the typing and the buttons work at the same time.

I thought the best way to approach this issue would be to use some sort of boolean. I tried to use `if(!x.hasFocus()){ allow buttons to be used}`, but this boolean only applies to the entire document and not specific textAreas.

So how do I make sure that the function of the keyboard presses do not happen when the textArea is selected?

Comment: Check if `event.target` is a textarea, or check if `document.activeElement` is a textarea, among others.

Comment: I see what you mean by activeElement and target, but I do not know a specific boolean for "is a textarea".

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Boolean for "is a textArea" is as follows: if(document.activeElement.tagName === "TEXTAREA"){//do things}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a global event listener for all textareas and input fields to not return anything when those buttons are pressed

```js
$(function(){
  $('textarea,input').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode===13 || e.keyCode==187 || e.keyCode===107 || e.keyCode===109 || e.keyCode==189 || e.keyCode==111 || e.keyCode===191) {
      return false;
    }
  })
})
```

then you can call proper functions for each key.

Comment: This is a nifty trick, but I do want the user to be able to use those keys when writing in the textArea :/

Comment: I am little confused. So when you focus on a textarea you don't want to type those letters but you also want users to be able to type them?

Comment: I apologize. You did answer the question that I posted, but I wrote it down incorrectly.